# Why does my Canon 5DmkIII shoot more than once in single shooting mode?

Tags: canon, error, canon-5d-mark-iii, shooting-mode

I noticed that sometimes my 5DMIII takes two shots as opposed to one (in single shooting mode). I'm not saying this happens all the times; in fact, it happened two or three times (top) in one month (and a few thousand shots).

Did anyone else have a similar issue?

Comment: How old is the camera and how clean do you keep it?

Comment: You aren't the only one... http://www.dpreview.com/forums/post/2981323 , http://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/3243746

Comment: Sounds like the camera doesn't come with very good debouncing circuitry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are holding it half way, it is a pretty soft press between a half way press and a full press.  Personally, I always use mine in one of the continuous drive modes, but I've had times when I've had it go off prematurely while I was adjusting focus or metering as a result of how light the second stage trigger is.

If you have a light touch, I'd hazard you are actually pressing it twice as a result of the camera shake from the mirror movement.  If you could reproduce it more often, you could try shooting with mirror lockup and see if that prevents it from occurring.

Answer (score 4):

Be sure you are selecting the *Single shooting* option in the *Drive mode* setting rather than the *One-Shot AF* option in the *AF mode* setting. When the *AF mode* is set to *One Shot*, the camera can still fire continuously. With *One Shot AF* once focus is achieved the focus will lock until the shutter is released or the half-press is released.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that there is something underneath the button (like dirt/condensation) that is causing the camera to fire more than once from time to time.

I should add that the MkIII has a very sensitive trigger and that I've bumped it several times accidentally and gotten off bursts of shots even in single fire mode.

As dpollitt has suggested above, [more than](http://www.dpreview.com/forums/post/2981323) one [person](http://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/3243746) is experiencing this albeit with 1D's and 7D's...